# Triangle a manifold

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, manifolds

Let $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and $\Delta:=\text{conv} \{x,y,z\}$ be a triangle. My question is: Is this triangle a $C^2$ submanifold in $\mathbb{R}^3$? The reason is, that I would need this fact in order to prove some Integration on submanifolds theorem on this triangle.

Comment: I [removed](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/631820/revisions) ([tag:comp]) tag. Was it some kind of typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An open triangle is a submanifold, a closed triangle is not.

Comment: how do you see this?

Comment: What do you mean? for an open triangle it is obvious (every point has a neighborhood diffeo to a neighborhood in $\mathbb{R}^2,$ for closed triangle, try to map a neighborhood of a vertex to a halfspace (smoothly).

Comment: This all depends on your definition of manifold... some people only consider the open triangle to be a manifold, while others think of manifolds with boundary or corners to be "manifolds."

Comment: @N.Owad I believe that they consider them to be "manifolds with corners", and it is true that most (all?) of the integration theory theory works on such, but that's not what the OP asked...

Comment: I cannot comment on what integration theory requires, I avoid taking integrals at all costs.

Comment: @N.Owad, well that throws a big chunk of mathematics out the window! =)